# Measurement protocol hit REFUND has no effect for revenue

Tags: google-analytics

I want to ask you why, when I send REFUND hit to analytics (analytics registered this hit), I see no effect to revenues. When I send refund, revenues should be lower.

Request:
[https://www.google-analytics.com/collect?v=1&t=event&tid={MY_UA_ID}&cid=fc2e0dee-5e15-4ae4-8374-cb89542d1c39&ec=Ecommerce&ea=Refund&ni=1&pa=refund&ti=583874](https://www.google-analytics.com/collect?v=1&t=event&tid=%7BMY_UA_ID%7D&cid=fc2e0dee-5e15-4ae4-8374-cb89542d1c39&ec=Ecommerce&ea=Refund&ni=1&pa=refund&ti=583874)

Revenues are still same as before hit.

Comment: SOLVED! Allowed Enhanced ecommerce in Ecommerce Settings solved this issue I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The refund hit to Analytics has no influence on the revenue but increases the Refund Amount value.